# Where are a theme's options stored and can I export them to be imported into freshly installed themes?

Tags: theme-options, configuration

Imagine that a person has a few premium themes that they use for clients. In those premium themes are many different options that can be set. Is it possible to set the theme's options to the most common and preferred choices and then export those options for later importation into other fresh WordPress installs with the same theme? That way one is not merely pointing and clicking their way through the various options over and over again for each new install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is theme depended and since most premium themes have their own framework/options panels then its going to be hard to tell where are the options are saved but in most cases they are saved in the options table in the database.

So the tricky part is to know what are the options names. You can look for them in the themes code either by searching for `add_option` , `update_option` and `register_settings`.

e.g. `grep -rnw 'wp-content/themes/' -e 'update_option'` to search from the command line.

Comment: Aha! Good to know! I'll pester my theme designer in that case. Is what I'm considering complete craziness or is it something that you've heard of being done before?

Comment: Not crazy at all, some of the better themes have a setting export/import functions built in.

Comment: FYI, after talking with the theme designer, all options for the theme are stored in the wp_options table.

Comment: For that specific theme.