# Where does Wordpress store the users customization in the theme

Tags: posts, customization

Good Day

When you are inside the wordpress ctrl panel, and you edit/create posts, do theme changes etc, where does Wordpress store all that content? In which files?

Thank you

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/25472/76260

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That information is stored in the MySQL database, not in files like you may be thinking of. They aren't stored in `.php` or `.html` files.

If you want to "see" how and where that data is stored the easiest way is to browse the database using a tool like PhpMyAdmin.

NOTE: Technically, there are files associated with the MySQL database but they aren't easy to get to and you can't read them except through the interface provided by the MySQL engine.

Comment: Any way to export those to another blog?

Answer (score 5):

WordPress does not save anything in files. All settings are stored in your database, normally the `options` table. Posts are stored in `posts` and `postmeta`.

You can have a look at the [Database Description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

If your theme is called *my-theme* the configuration is stored as serialized PHP object in a option name called theme_mods_*my-theme* in the `wp_options` table in your Wordpress database.
Use any Database editor tool to execute the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE 'theme_mods_%'
```

with will return all the customizations for every theme you have in your wordpress install.

Export the  query results to a SQL plain text file. Then, when you update your theme, you import your SQL file again and voilà, you have your customizatons again.